# How does SSH find the destination from name only?

Tags: networking, macos, ssh

I have a weird case where I can connect to a remote host named `obiwan` by simply running `ssh cip@obiwan`. I cannot understand how SSH knows what `obiwan` corresponds to.

In my `/etc/hosts` I don't have any entry related to `obiwan`. Promise ! I have 3 lines which are **not** obiwan, and these ones which were already there:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I thought it might come from ssh config, but I can run `\ssh -v -F none cip@obiwan` and it works. So no config file, and also note the backslash, meaning no alias / function taken into account.

If I try to `ping obiwan`, I get `cannot resolve obiwan: Unknown host`. But, interestingly, I get tab completion when I do `ping obi<tab>`. So something, somewhere, knows about it...

If I `dig obiwan` I don't get any `ANSWER SECTION`.

How can I figure out why this works?

Thank you !

Comment: How remote is the host (same subnet or further away)? Can you ping `obiwan.local`? Does `dig +search obiwan` find the host? Does macOS have the `getent ahosts obiwan` command?

Comment: The name `obiwan` is broadcasted by ZeroConf / Bonjour ?

Comment: @user1686 `obiwan` is indeed same subnet, forgot to mention. `obiwan.local` doesn't give anything, but you reminded me that we can reach some local stuff with a different suffix, let's call it `company.li`. And indeed, I can ping `obiwan.company.li`. I don't have `getent` on macos, and there's no result for `dig +search obiwan`

Comment: @PierU I don't know. Any pointers on how to check ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă I don't really known, it's just an hypothesis

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, my traffic was being forwarded through a SOCKS proxy to another server on the same network. This server has `obiwan` in its `/etc/hosts`, so I believe due to this combination my SSH could find the `obiwan` destination.

After killing the SOCKS proxy, `ssh -F none obiwan` no longer works, cannot resolve hostname `obiwan`, as expected.

There is still the `obiwan.company.li` that can be pinged, like user1695 suggested in the comments. But I'm not sure that this has any contribution.